# Too many tuple failures- Storm Topology

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

I have a storm application in which I have 1 spout and 5 bolts. Topology is working fine. but I gives `Too many tuple failures` error after 30min. In 1st bolt to 2nd bolt only 20% data is processed due to some analytics condition. 80% data discarded. I think this error occurred due to 80% data discarded or anything else. I don't know what's the reason and how to solve it.

Comment: Do you `ack` the input tuples in 1st bolt that is discarded?

Comment: I dont need that tuple. What can do in this condition. I am doing nothing in ack method

Comment: example --in 1st bolt there is 100 tuples. I have some condition in 1st bolt and only 20 tuples are going in 2nd bolt.

Comment: can you enrich your post with a nice storm UI screenshot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use fault-tolerance in Storm (ie, assign message IDs to tuples in your spout), you need to `ack` **all** tuples in the bolt that consumes the spout's output. Even if you discard some tuples due to a filter condition, because "discarding a tuple" still means, that this tuple is fully processed, ie, you need to tell Storm about this -- otherwise, Storm thinks something went wrong (due to timeout) and fails the tuple.

KafkaSpouts assign message IDs automatically. You just need to ack all incoming tuples:

```java
void execute(Tuple input) {
    if(input-is-forwarded) {
       collector.emit(input, new Values(/* generate output tuple */);
    }
    // ack tuple (regardless if forwarded or discarded)
    collector.ack(input);
}
```

Comment: I am using KafkaSpout. How can I tell storm that I have to discard the tuples.

Comment: Yes. And also in all other bolts. Each time, an input tuple is completely processed, you need to `ack` it, by calling `collector.ack(input);`. **Caution** after acking a tuple, you cannot use it as an anchor any more!

Comment: to "manualy" ack the tuples he needs to extend the BaseRichBolt, conversely if he extends the BaseBasicBolt the ack is done automatically after the tuple is processed. I think he is having tuples failing by some other reason.

Comment: Tuple are failing due to filter. I am doing filtering in 1st bolt. I am using BaseRichBolt but problem accured. I trying manually ack. Working on it. Lets see, will run perfect or not.

Comment: Thanks Mathias it's working. I have a question. I an doing manually ack for all tuple in all bolt. what's it meaning. give acknowlegment for all tuple. but in my 2nd bolt only 20% data is processing and it ack for all tuple , same for all bolt. I think it will decrease the efficiency. Can you please decsribe this.

Comment: If you enable fault-tolerance it always has an high impact on performance. You can use Trindent, to reduce this overhead. (Or run without fault-tolerance of you application allows for it.) What I do not understand is, what you mean by **"only 20% of data is processed"**? If you apply a filter and discard a tuple, this discarded tuple was processed, too. So even if you produce output for only 20% of your input data (and no output for 80% of your input data) you still process 100%. You might have a look here too: https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Guaranteeing-message-processing.html